# Back button does not return leadbolt ads view to Android App

Tags: html, cordova, ads, leadbolt

After an ad is displayed and i hit the back button (on the hardware or adview), leadbolt takes me to a dark screen and doesn't return to my app.

Am using phonegap 1.3.0 and the ad type is a content unlocker.

Any ideas on what i can do about it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to implement this ?

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.2.0/phonegap_events_events.md.html#backbutton

Comment: Thanks for the insight. Is there any leadbolt event that is called when an ad is closed? I would like to close the ad using the close button on the adview.